# Keeping track of time while recording

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

I have an AVAudioRecorder that records sound. I also have a label. I would like to update the text on the label every second to show the recording time. How can I do this?

Comment: Check this sample code from Apple to play a file using AVAudioPlayer. It will give you an idea how to track the time. Implement the same in AvAudioRecorder.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/avTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008636

Comment: There is also a nice Swift implementation [here by Ben Dodson](https://github.com/bendodson/AudioRecorderViewController-Swift/blob/master/AudioRecorderViewController/AudioRecorderViewController.swift).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the currentTime property of AVAudioRecorder (audioRecorder.currentTime) to get the time, as an `NSTimeInterval`, since the beginning of the recording which u can use to display on your label.

Comment: But how can I make a metjod which refreshes the label constantly?

Comment: Call the method periodically using a timer or something. U can set the text for the label within the method. Note that u need to make the AVAudioRecorder object as a class variable.

Comment: Yes i have done made the AVAudioRecorder object as a class variable. And thanks Ill try using a timer. Hope it works :)

Comment: All the best. Let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 7):

do like this:

```
  - (IBAction)startStopRecording:(id)sender 
    {
           //If the app is note recording, we want to start recording, and make the record button say "STOP"
        if(!self.isRecording)
        {
            self.isRecording = YES;  //this is the bool value to store that recorder recording
            [self.recordButton setTitle:@"STOP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedFile settings:nil error:nil];
            [recorder prepareToRecord];
            [recorder record];

            myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];  //this is nstimer to initiate update method
        }

        else
        {
            self.isRecording = NO;
            [self.recordButton setTitle:@"REC" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [recorder stop];
            recorder = nil;    
            [myTimer invalidate];
        }

    }

- (void)updateSlider {
    // Update the slider about the music time
    if([recorder isRecording])
    {

        float minutes = floor(recorder.currentTime/60);
        float seconds = recorder.currentTime - (minutes * 60);

        NSString *time = [[NSString alloc] 
                                    initWithFormat:@"%0.0f.%0.0f",
                                    minutes, seconds];
        recordTimeLabel.text = time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you stop the timer somewhere? ^^

Comment: @marsbear, Yes, Thanx for notify, i have added it when user stop recording. Also its preferable to stop timer in ViewDidDepear/ViewWillDispear, So if user go back without stoping than still timer will stop.